# Swift 4 error on Release configuration

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

If you run this code on Xcode 9.1 using the Optimization level `Fast, whole Module Optimization`, it crashes. If the Optimization level is set to `None`, everything goes fine.

Does anyone have an idea of the issue?

```
protocol FooProtocol {
    func foo()
}

class FooProtocolImplementation : NSObject, FooProtocol {
    func foo() {}
}

var set: Set<AnyHashable> = []
_ = set.insert(FooProtocolImplementation())
let array = set.flatMap { $0 as? FooProtocol } // filtering out nils
_ = array[0] // # error (EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

Comment: What if you don't inherit from `NSObject`?

Comment: It does not work

Comment: What would happen if you set `FooProtocol` to be class protocol: `protocol FooProtocol: class`? And if you can provide more detail like on which line it crashes.

Comment: It also crashes at the line _ = array[0] // error (EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Answer (score 0):

Apple reported it as a bug and fixed it in Xcode 9.3